# I am creating weather app by using Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working  on weather app. For that I want to search weather by city. I am getting weather information by city but the problem is 
i.e; In the search box when I am typing anything like
ex:dfdfdfdf (or) 12435 I am getting the weather information.It should not happened it should retrieve only cities weather information. I haved Edited my code. Below is full code

```
.controller('SearchInWeatherH01Ctrl', function ($scope, $state, Weather, $resource, $http,$rootScope) {
    $scope.checkWeather = function (city) {
        $http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + encodeURIComponent(city))
        .success(function (response) {
            if (response.results.length) {
                if (response.results.length) {
                    var location = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                    $scope.lat = location.lat;
                    $scope.longit = location.lng;
                    Weather.getAtLocation(location.lat, location.lng).then(function (resp) {
                        if (city == null ) {
                             alert("Please Enter City Name");
                             return false;
                        }
                       $scope.current = resp.data;
                       console.log('GOT CURRENT',JSON.stringify( $scope.current));
                       $rootScope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        }, function (error) {
             alert('Unable to get current conditions');
             console.error(error);
        });
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you edit your question so that it will be more clear what exactly what is your problem and what are you asking?

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. We don't know where the response comes from, and also you are using the variable city, which isn't defined in the example you show us.

Comment: 12435 is a valid Zip Code so, it outputs some result. [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=12435](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=12435). No results are shown by dfdfdf - [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=dfdfdfdf](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=dfdfdfdf)

Comment: For me Below is the result  when I am typing any letters in search box: "latitude":40.5169617,"longitude":-74.4602393,"timezone":"America/New_York"

Comment: Or if there is any "if condition" to retrieve weather information if city is valid or else it should display error message